# Compability of Kenko DGX PR0300 2.0X C-AF F4.5 for Canon and a Canon 55-250mm lens

Tags: lens, canon, teleconverter, compatibility

Can the [Kenko DGX PR0300 2.0X C-AF F/4.5 Lens for Canon (Black)](http://www.amazon.in/gp/aw/d/B002BIBDUUcan) be used with a Canon 55-250mm lens?

Answer (score 1):

It is a 2x teleconverter. For all practical purposes, 2x teleconverters are not very useful on slow zoom lenses because it simply costs too much light - two full stops.

The Canon 55-200 f/4-5.6 with a 2x teleconverter will become a 110-400 f/8-11. Keeping the shutter speeds reasonable on such a long and slow lens will not be easy. Autofocus will struggle, and it will not be easy to see in the viewfinder what you are doing.

So, in conclusion: Even if it may work in a purely technical sense you probably won't want to do it.

Comment: Autofocus will not be slow. It will be totally nonfunctional.

Comment: Depends on whether the converter tells the camera that it is there or not. If no, the camera will try to AF... in good light and with a high-contrast subject it may even succeed. If yes, the camera will not even try.

Comment: It will try, but in all likelihood unless you are in some VERY bright light all it will do is hunt. The additional glass in teleconverters tend to reduce contrast as well as the effective aperture.

Comment: I own this teleconverter and my APS-C cameras (7D, 50D) struggle to AF in daylight when it is attached to an f/4 lens. They hunt and hunt but rarely ever lock focus unless I am using an f/2.8 lens. The FF 5DII, with a wider baseline for the focus array, does a little better, but only in VERY bright light. To use a 2X teleconverter with an APS-C camera you need an f/2.8 or faster lens if you expect to have *usable* AF.

Comment: The AF in most Canon cameras just plain stop working at all once the camera knows that it is shooting a lens with worse than f/5.6 max aperture... and they don't do this to be mean, but because it just plain doesn't work very well with such a small aperture.

Comment: It varies by model when the teleconverter is reporting the aperture correctly. But the Kenko seems to take advantage of the fact that one legacy of the early EOS communication system allows a lens to report a different maximum aperture and currently selected aperture. This seems to have been included when the EOS system was developed to allow for lenses with manual aperture rings. The Kenko 2X reports f/5.6 as the maximum aperture but also tells the camera it is currently set to f/8 when f/4 lenses are attached to it.

Comment: There are some Sigma and Tamron lenses with maximum apertures between f/5.6 and f/8 that also seem to take advantage of this provision. Almost all Canon digital bodies will at least *attempt* to focus with the Tamron 18-270mm f/3.5-6.3 even when the focal length is set to 270mm. They don't totally shut off AF like they do when a Canon lens/extender combo f//8 or narrower is attached.

Answer (score 0):

The Kenko Pro 300 1.4x TC says it will not work with an EF-S lens like the 55-250.  Everything I've read says the 2x is the same.  So, regardless of AF issues, I'd say this is a no go.

Comment: You know, the red circle doesn't align with the white box when I try it, as you'd expect.